# Voting to close a question from the flag queue cause "undefined more votes needed" to appear when the question is closed

Tags: bug, flags, closed-questions, moderator-abilities

I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392275/changing-the-height-of-a-div-on-click in the flag queue, and I voted to close it. As you see, I am the last one who voted to close it.

After I did it, the flag queue showed the following.

> [image: screenshot]

It should have shown the question was closed, but "undefined more votes needed" is what appears between brackets.